# Grid not changing

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm having issues with my grid with not showing the dimensions I want. I have a 2×2 grid:
L1 is a product image,
r1 is a newsletter sign up,
R2 is a heading with browse-all link,
R2 is a product grid – 6 product images with product details and star review.

From my understanding, the grid template I have should mean that L1 and R1 take up ⅓ of the page, and L2, R2 should take up the other ⅔.

However this is not happening. Instead, the L1 and R1 are squashed to the left maybe ⅛ of the page, and no mater what I do, the width of L1, R1 don't change.

```css
.shop-page-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  gap: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

.L1,
.R1,
.L2,
.R2 {
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

.R1,
.L2,
.R2 {
  padding: 20px;
}

.L1 img,
.R2 img {
  width: 100%;
  /* Adjust this if needed */
  height: auto;
}

.R1 .newsletter-content {
  text-align: left;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

form label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

form input {
  max-width: 200px;
}

form button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.image-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.image-grid img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.browse-all-button {
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.image-grid .small-image {
  width: 100%;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  max-width: 150px;
  /* Set a maximum width to control size */
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.R2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 200px;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 220px;
}

.product img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.product-info {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.product h4,
.product p {
  margin: 0;
}

.star-rating {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fa-star.checked {
  color: gold;
}

.fa-star {
  color: white;
}

HTML
<div class="shop-page-grid">
   <div class="L1">
     <!-- Content for L1 - Single Image -->
      <img src="Images/Catergories 3.jpg" alt="Single Image" 
class="img-fluid small-image">
   </div>
   <div class="R1">
      <!-- Content for R1 - Newsletter Content and Form -->
      <div class="newsletter-content">
         <h2>Newsletter</h2>
      </div>
      <form action="subscribe" method="post">
         <label for="email">Email:</label>
         <input type="email" id="email" name="email" 
placeholder="Enter your email" required>
         <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
      </form>
   </div>
   <div class="L2">
      <!-- Content for L2 - Shop Local Products -->
      <h3>Shop Local Products</h3>
      <p>Explore a variety of local products and support your 
community.</p>
      <button class="browse-all-button">Browse All</button>
   </div>
   <div class="R2">
     <div class="image-grid">
         <!-- Product 1 -->
         <div class="product">
            <img src="Images/Product 1.jpg" class="img-fluid 
small-image" alt="Product 1">
            <h4>Product Name 1</h4>
            <p>$50.00</p>
            <div class="star-rating">
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Product 2 -->
          <div class="product">
            <img src="Images/Product 2.jpg" class="img-fluid 
small-image" alt="Product 2">
            <h4>Product Name 2</h4>
            <p>$65.00</p>
            <div class="star-rating">
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Product 3 -->
         <div class="product">
            <img src="Images/Product 3.jpg" class="img-fluid 
small-image" alt="Product 3">
            <h4>Product Name 3</h4>
            <p>$80.00</p>
            <div class="star-rating">
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Product 4 -->
         <div class="product">
            <img src="Images/Product 4.jpg" class="img-fluid 
small-image" alt="Product 4">
            <h4>Product Name 4</h4>
            <p>$80.00</p>
            <div class="star-rating">
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Product 5 -->
         <div class="product">
            <img src="Images/Product 5.jpg" class="img-fluid 
small-image" alt="Product 5">
            <h4>Product Name 5</h4>
            <p>$80.00</p>
            <div class="star-rating">
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Product 6 -->
         <div class="product">
            <img src="Images/Product 6.jpg" class="img-fluid 
small-image" alt="Product 6">
            <h4>Product Name 6</h4>
            <p>$80.00</p>
            <div class="star-rating">
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
               <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you got a typo in grid-template-columns? Did you mean 1fr 2fr?

Comment: Thanks for helping, Apologies yes it should be 1fr 2fr its a typo uploading it onto here, but is correct in VS Code

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add HTML to the Stack Snippet I added to your question. That way we can see the code in action and more easily see what's wrong.

Comment: again apologies if its messy, this is my first code

Comment: You have several fixed px values which are quite large. e.g. 200px. This is a lot for a gap - on my reasonably large laptop screen 3 of them take up neary half the screen. I'd suggest first going through the code making those gaps and paddings much smaller, otherwise R2 in particular has to have too much space allocated to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using percentages

```
grid-template-columns: 33% 67%;
```

fr unit uses the leftover space. The problem is that your product grid is taking up too much space, so the first column of your grid does not have much leftover space.

Also, your product class can make good use of a direction column property

```
flex-direction: column;
```

Comment: thank you so much, that worked perfect, ive been trying to get it right all day so thank you!